# Splunk Dropdown based on a field from string result

Tags: splunk

I have a splunk search that returns String with the format A;B;C
I want to create a dropdown in a splunk dashboard based on the first field (A).

So my problem here, is first, how to extract the first string before semicolon.
And Second, how to use that field dynamically in the dropdown

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add more details of the issue that you are facing.Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi, could you give a snippet of your dashboard, you can use directives inside search to extract and create tokens when search is finished so you could create 3 new tokens with diferents values (IE A,B,C). with the information provided its imposible to me give you more help